# using dimension reduction before real data classification

Tags: r, classification, pca, categorical-data, dimensionality-reduction

I  have a dataset containing 13 features and a column which represents the class.

I want to do a binary classification based on the features, but I am using a method which can work only with 2 features. So I need to reduce the features to 2 columns.

My problem is that some of my features are real valued like age, heart rate and blood pressure and some of them are categorical like type of the chest pain etc.

Which method of dimensionality reduction suits my work?

Is PCA a good choie?

If so, how can I use PCA for my categorical features?

I work with R.

Comment: From Review: "I work with R" - please EDIT your question, remove one of these tags (e.g. preprocessor, or classification, I can not chose it for you) and add the "R" tag. This will help getting more answers. Is it also possible provide any concrete example? That would help us help you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can just code the categorical features to number, for example, 1 represent cat, 2 represent dog, and so on. 
PCA is a useful feature selection method, but it is used for linear data, you can just try it and see the result. kernel PCA is used for nonlinear data, you can also try this.
other method contain LLE, ISOMAP,CCA,LDA... you can just try those methods and find a better result.

Answer (score 0):

Check H2O library for GLRM models ([link to docs](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/glrm.html#generalized-low-rank-models-glrm)). It can handle categorical variables.
If that does not work for you, target encoding techniques could be useful before applying PCA.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using CatBoost (https://catboost.ai, https://github.com/catboost/catboost) - a new gradient boosting library with good handling of categorical features.